# Writing function to check state's machine current state [Lua/Love2d]

Tags: lua, game-development, love2d

I'm learning game development with LÖVE2D and Lua and lately I've been using a state machine class. I haven't coded the class myself, but I've went through the code and I think I pretty much got it, besides this one problem.

The thing is, I'm trying to prompt the class for its current state, just so I can use it inside an *if*, but no matter what, I cannot get it right.

Here's the relevant code of the class:

```
StateMachine = Class{}

function StateMachine:init(states)
    self.empty = {
        render = function() end,
        update = function() end,
        enter = function() end,
        exit = function() end
    }
    self.states = states or {} -- [name] -> [function that returns states]
    self.current = self.empty
end

function StateMachine:change(stateName, enterParams)
    assert(self.states[stateName]) -- state must exist!
    self.current:exit()
    self.current = self.states[stateName]()
    self.current:enter(enterParams)
end
```

What I'm basically trying to do is:

```
function StateMachine:is(stateName)
    if self.current == self.states[stateName] then 
        -- this never executes
        return true
    end

    return false
end
```

I've tried changing `self.states[stateName]` to other things to test it out and also tried printing stuff to the console to see why the comparison is never true. It seems `self.current` returns a pointer to a table and thus never matches whatever is on the other side of the comparison operator.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You can change the implementation of `StateMachine:change` so that it saves the name of the entering state.  Then just compare names (strings) when you need.

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff I did that, exactly, and then created some helper functions to debug with. Thanks a lot for your input, it was really helpful!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`self.current` is set to the `return` value of `self.states[stateName]` in `StateMachine:change`

```lua
function StateMachine:change(stateName, enterParams)
    ...
    self.current = self.states[stateName]() -- note the () indicating the call
```

This means, unless the return value is `self`, `self.current` will not be equal to the function or object `self.states[stateName]` that it is compared to in `StateMachine:is`

```lua
function StateMachine:is(stateName)
    if self.current == self.states[stateName] then -- here we are comparing the function to the return value
```

---

I would suggest expanding your state object to have a `:getName` function that would return the `stateName` or to store the name in your `StateMachine` under a key such as `currentStateName`.

Comment: That actually worked flawlessly. I created a currentStateName in the  StateMachine and passed it stateName on the StateMachine:change(...)  function.

Just to clarify, there is a constructor function stored at self.states[stateName] that returns a state object, so, if I understood it correctly, then self.current points to the object created by that constructor. That's why I could never compare it to another instance of self.states[stateName](), because I would be receiving another object at a different address and thus, comparing was always false. Is that right?

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same question & I'd like to add--perhaps some of the comments explain this in language I just didn't understand :D--but in the getCurrentState function I created I had to do this:

```
function StateMachine:getCurrentState()
    variable = self.currentStateName
    return variable
```

where ofc variable is just some placeholder. but I had to grab the reference that self.currentStateName was pointing to, otherwise the comparison always failed.